# python check if anagram on a string

Tags: python, anagram

hello i have made a function that checks if two strings are a anagram but, i don't know how to implement it on a full length sentence, e.g:

- 'voLa' 'alVo' -----> these words are an anagram and it returns True

but what im trying to do is on an egg like this:

- 'hello vola alvo my name is ...' , -----> 'hello my name is ...'

And i dont know how to do it, can anyone help me?

```
 def anagram(a, b):
   if len(a)==len(b) and sorted(a)==sorted(b):
     return True
   else:
     return False
```

Comment: So do you want to remove anagrams from a string?

Comment: you are trying to remove the anagrams? what's the general condition it can be anywhere in the text or only one word next to other?

Comment: @UlisesBussi, im just going to lay down the whole problem. This function receives a string filled with errors, there's a function i have made prior that corrects those errors and returns a string, but with anagrams. this final function is supposed to return the filtered string with the corrected words and the anagrams removed, leaving only their first occurrence, the anagrams are evaluated after correcting the words and only anagrams that correspond to different words (character string different from previous words are removed, egg 'data tada base has wrong data', having tada removed.

Comment: Split the string into a list of words. Go through the list, testing if a word is an anagram of any of the other words. If not, add it to the result list.

Comment: What do you mean by an "egg"?

Comment: @Barmar thank you!, btw egg-> example (just so i can type it faster)

Comment: The abbreviation for example is `e.g.`, not `egg`.

Comment: Do you need a word by word anagram match or is your issue simply to exclude spaces from the process ?  (e.g. is "William Shakespeare" an anagram of  "I am a weakish speller", or would you only accept something like "restful Santa" : "Satan fluster")

Answer (score 0):

To filter occurrences of anagrams, you could place the original words in a dictionary where the key is formed of the sorted letters.  Any subsequent word would find the anagram by looking up its sorted letters in the dictionary.  To isolate words, a regular expression would be best because you can use the sub() function to replace words with the result of a function.

```
import re

def stripAnagram(match):
    word = match.group().lower()
    key  = "".join(sorted(word))
    if anagrams.setdefault(key,word) != word:
        return ''
    return match.group()

s =  'data tada base has wrong data'
anagrams = dict()
s = re.sub(r'\w+',stripAnagram,s)
print(s)
data  base has wrong data
```

Answer (score 0):

If the anagram appears next to the original word, you can modify a little your function to detect anagrams and do:

```
def isAnagram(a, b):
    if sorted(a.lower())==sorted(b.lower()) :
        return True
    else:
        return False

#this is the same as the above
# def isAnagram(a, b):
#    return sorted(a.lower())==sorted(b.lower())
```

then remove the anagrams:

```
def removeAnagrams(phrase):
    words = phrase.split(' ')
    newWords = []
    oldWord = ''
    for word in words:
        if not isAnagram(word, oldWord):
            newWords.append(word)
        oldWord = word
    print(newWords)
    newPhrase = ' '.join(newWords)
    return newPhrase
```

and test:

```
phrase = "There was a beautifyll day. The saw was sharped"
print(removeAnagrams(phrase))
#There was a beautifyll day. The saw sharped
```